# Best way to create a entity in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, entity

I am making a `Model` class which should look like this:

```
public class ModelSection
{
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public string SectionReportName { get; set; }
}
```

I am making a instance of it like this...

```
ModelSection ms = new ModelSection();
ms.SectionReportName = subreports[0].ToString();
ms.SectionID = SectionID1;
ms.SectionName = SectionName1;

ModelSection ms1 = new ModelSection();
ms1.SectionReportName = subreports[1].ToString();
ms1.SectionID = SectionID2;
ms1.SectionName = SectionName2;

ModelSection ms2 = new ModelSection();
ms2.SectionReportName = subreports[2].ToString();
ms2.SectionID = SectionID3;
ms2.SectionName = SectionName3;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please be more precise with what you're asking for! What exactly do you want to improve?

Comment: I have 3 reports which I need to import into one main report and first thing I need to do is to create entities of those 3 subreports... For now, I need to hardcode values, but later I need to make it generics. I don't know what to say anymore. @Dr.Coconut

Comment: If you have any possibility to access the section Ids and Names via an indexer, you could place that logic inside a loop and add the newly created ModelSection objects to a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try doing this

```
 ModelSection ms = new ModelSection {
                    SectionReportName = subreports[0].ToString(),
                    SectionID = SectionID1,
                    SectionName = SectionName1
                    };
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I choose this because it looks nicer, but I need to work more on this. Anyway tnx @fabrzio

Comment: @SidBroklyn check for Collection Initializers in the link to handle many objects initialization, maybe it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more like the following.

```
ModelSelection ms1 = new ModelSelection()
        { 
            SectionID = SectionID1,
            SectionName = SectionName1,
            SectionReportName = subreports[0].ToString()
        };

ModelSelection ms2 = new ModelSelection()
        { 
            SectionID = SectionID2,
            SectionName = SectionName2,
            SectionReportName = subreports[0].ToString()
        };
```

Comment: This!!!...and then you can repeat this with some loop if you want to create multiple entities